# Show $f=f^*$ including inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space with inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ and $f:V\to V$. Show that if $\langle f(v),v\rangle\in \mathbb{R}$ for $v \in V$, then $f=f^∗$.

I was thinking of taking the inner product of $\langle f(v),v \rangle$ but I dont really have any clear idea

Comment: You're not very clear on any of the details here. Is $f$ an endomorphism? What exactly is $f^*$ in this notation? Also you should probably include more details on thoughts you had, things you considered trying, etc.

Comment: Is $f$ a linear map? and $f^*$ the adjoint operator of $f$. Please clarify !

Answer (score 5):

Note that for all $v \in V$
\begin{align}
0 & =\langle fv,v\rangle-\overline{\langle fv,v\rangle} \\
& =\langle fv,v\rangle-\langle v,fv\rangle\\
&=\langle fv,v\rangle -\langle f^{\star}v,v\rangle \\
&=\langle (f-f^{\star})v,v\rangle
\end{align}

So $(f-f^{\star})v=\vec{0}$, hence $f=f^{\star}$.

Comment: if you use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<`and `>` you'll get a better formatting. I edited it for you, I hope you don't mind (you can always rollback if you want)

Comment: No problem!  Thanks for the info.

Comment: This, of course, assumes that $\langle g(x),x \rangle = 0$ for all $x$ implies that $g = 0$.  Note that this is true over complex vector spaces, but not over *real* vector spaces.  In the context of real vector spaces, this only guarantees that $g$ is skew-adjoint.

Comment: Jup, forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 4):

It suffices to show that $\newcommand{\ip}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$
$\ip{f(x),y} = \ip{x,f(y)}$
holds for every $x,y \in V$.

In order to show that this is the case: note that

- $\ip{f(x),x} = \ip{x,f(x)}$
- $\ip{f(y),y} = \ip{y,f(y)}$
- $\ip{f(x+y),x+y} = \ip{x+y,f(x+y)}$
- $\ip{f(x + iy),x+iy} = \ip{x+iy,f(x+iy)}$

The rest is a matter of applying the sesqui-linearity of the inner product.